# Ergodic measure

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $m$ be a $\phi$ Ergodic measure on a space $X$, where $\phi$ is a homeomorphism on $X$. Let $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$ be two $\phi$-invariant $\sigma$ finite measures on $X$ such that $m$ is equivalent to both $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$. I want to prove that $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$ are scalar multiplies of each other. By Radon Nikodym theorem there is a $\mu_2$ measurable function $f$ such that $\mu_1(B)=\int fd\mu_2$ for all Borel sets $B$. I proved that $f=f\circ \phi$, $\mu_2$ almost everywhere. How ergodicity of $m$ will imply that $f$ is a constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints: For any Borel set $A$ we have $\mu_2(f^{-1}(A))\in \{0,1\}$ becaue $f^{-1}(A)=\phi^{-1}(f^{-1}(A))$. Let $c=\sup \{x: f^{-1}(-\infty, x)=0\}$. Show that $f=c$ a .e. $[\mu _2]$.

Comment: So I have to prove that $\mu_2(\{y:f(y)\neq c\})=0$. $\{y:f(y)\neq c\}=f^{-1}(-\infty,c)\cup f^{-1}(c,\infty)$. The first set has $\mu_2$ measure zero. But the second one can have $\mu_2$ measure 1.

Comment: @AAh Show that $\mu_2 (f<c-\frac  1n)=0$ and $\mu_2 (f>c+\frac  1n)=0$ for all $n$. Then take the limit.

Comment: @AAh Yes, that is correct.

Comment: how $\mu_2(f>c+\frac{1}{n})=0$?

Comment: @AAh For any invariant set $A$ either $A$ or $A^{c}$ has measure $0$. What happens of $\mu_2(f>c+\frac 1 n)$ is not zero?

Comment: If it is not zero it has measure 1 and so its compliment $\{f\leq c+\frac{1}{n}\}$ has measure zero. Which inturn imply  $\{f< c+\frac{1}{n}\}$  has measure 0 which will contradict that c is the supremum. Am I correct?

Comment: @AAh Exactly! That is the proof.